# What did I do wrong in my orbital notation for this Os (Osmium) question?

Tags: electrons, orbitals, notation

I was given a question where I had to write the orbital notation of Osmium (Os) and I got it wrong.

**The question:**

6s2 --> ↑↓  4f --> ↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓↑↓  5d6 --> ↑↓↑↓↑↑

The arrows above are my answer. What did I do wrong? I think it might be my answer to 5d6 but I am not sure. How many unpaired electrons are in Osmium?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Hund's rule of Maximum Multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hund%27s_rule_of_maximum_multiplicity), a higher spin multiplicity is more stable. In simple terms, this means that a given atom would try to have the maximum number of unpaired electrons. For Osmium, which has a $\mathrm{5d^6}$ configuration, there are 5 d-orbitals and 6 electrons to fill, so the maximum number of unpaired electrons in this arrangement would be 4 (two electrons pair up and occupy one orbital, and the remaining 4 occupy a single orbital each). Here's the orbital diagram (taken from this [Chemistry Libretexts article](https://chem.libretexts.org/Under_Construction/Purgatory/Essential_Chemistry_(Curriki)/Unit_1%3A_Atomic_and_Molecular_Structure/1.4%3A_Electron_Configuration_and_Orbital_Diagrams), which you should read)

[image: Osmium orbital diagram]